# C# IDisposable, Dispose(), lock (this)

Tags: c#, .net

I am new to programming. I am studying chapter 14 of John Sharp's Microsoft Visual C # Step by Step 9ed.
And I do not understand a number of points.

The author writes:

**...it (finalizer) can run anytime after the last reference to an object has disappeared. So it is possible that the finalizer might actually be invoked by the garbage collector on its own thread while the Dispose method is being run, especially if the Dispose method has to do a significant amount of work.**

**1)** Here I have a **first question**, how is this possible? After all, GC CLR destroys the object as correctly noticed when there are no more links to it. But if there are no references, how then can simultaneously still work the method of an object (Dispose()) to which nothing else refers? Yes, there are no links, but the method is not completed and GC CLR will try to delete the method object that still works?

Further, the author proposes to use lock (this) to circumvent this problem (parallel calls to Dispose ()) and clarifies that this can be detrimental to performance by immediately suggesting another strategy described earlier in the chapter.

```
class Example : IDisposable
{
    private Resource scarce;       // scarce resource to manage and dispose
    private bool disposed = false; // flag to indicate whether the resource
                                   // has already been disposed
    ...
    ~Example()
    {
        this.Dispose(false);
    }

    public virtual void Dispose()
    {
        this.Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!this.disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                // release large, managed resource here
                ...
            }
            // release unmanaged resources here
            ...
                this.disposed = true;
        }
    }

    //other methods
}
```

**2)** I understand how it works and why it is needed, but I have problems with mentioning exactly the parallel execution of `this.Dispose(true)` and `this.Dispose(false)`.

**Which in the proposed last solution will not allow GC CLR to call the `this.Dispose(false)` method in its thread in parallel through the destructor in the same way as before while `this.Dispose(true)` will still be executed previously launched explicitly?**

At first glance, this is a `GC.SuppressFinalize` (this) construct, but it should work only after the end of this.Dispose (true), and by condition it is executed long enough for GC CLR in its thread to start the deconstructor and `this.Dispose(false)`.

As I understand it, nothing prevents and we get only a repeat of discarding unmanaged resources (files, connections to databases, and so on), but we don’t get a repeat of discarding managed resources (for example, a large multidimensional array).

It turns out that it is permissible to repeatedly drop unmanaged resources and it is unacceptable to repeatedly discard managed resources? And this is better than using the lock (this) construct?

Comment: `if there are no references, how then can simultaneously still work the method of an object (Dispose()) to which nothing else refers` - https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100813-00/?p=13153, also https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100810-00/?p=13193.

Comment: *normally*, if an instance `Dispose()` method is being invoked, then the `this` is still the `arg0` parameter, even if it isn't anywhere else - so the reference does exist. I *assume* the author is talking about some scenario where the call has been inlined away, but for that scenario to be a useful one, we'd also need to assume that it doesn't talk to any of the *fields* during the dispose, because the fields *also* reference `this` which would need to be preserved; so...  this sounds like an incredibly hypothetical situation which can't really have any observable side effects!

Comment: There is an answer to the first question. Yes it is possible. It just works that way.

Comment: "by condition it is executed long enough for GC CLR in its thread to start the deconstructor and this.Dispose(false)." - I don't buy that; becaus the `GC.SuppressFinalize(this)` **is by itself a reference to the object**. Since the GC checks the stack, that object is reachable, so: is not eligible for collect; meaning: the `GC.SuppressFinalize(this)` is serving the same purpose as `GC.KeepAlive(this)` here (there's nothing special about `KeepAlive` - it is just an opaque method)

Comment: @MarcGravell **"is by itself a reference to the object. Since the GC checks the stack, that object is reachable, so: is not eligible for collect"**
That is, GC.SuppressFinalize (this) does not expect when all previous operations will work (even though there will be a thousand)? And it just says GC do not touch me when GC gets on the stack to this object and checks whether it needs to be removed?

Comment: GC doesn't care about "me", but: it crawls the stack-frames looking for reads against references; a read on "this" aka `arg0` (for example for `GC.SuppressFinalize(this)` or an access of `this.someField`) means that the object against that reference is reachable, so: should not be collected. The only time your object could be collected during a live method is if it *doesn't touch `this`/`arg0` again during that method* (or interior pointers via `ref` locals). In which case: you can't observe any side-effects or interactions *anyway*, because there *can't be any*?

Comment: But: there *is* a scenario where this could cause bad side-effects, which is when you have *unmanaged values* (pointers etc) in the object, and you read them into locals at the start of the long method, and never touch `this` again during the method. **In that scenario**, yes, it could go badly. Is that even remotely like your scenario? If it isn't, it shouldn't be a problem. If you're touching other (non-this) **managed** objects in a finalizer: that's a bug in your finalizer *anyway*. In the unmanaged scenario: just `GC.KeepAlive(this)` (or `SuppressFinalize`) at the end of the method: done

Comment: I still do not know what pointers are, I just read a concrete simple example in the book and I did not understand. I thought that the operations are performed sequentially in the block one by one and the method cannot be called `GC.SuppressFinalize(this)` until the previous operation is over (`this.Dispose(true)`).

Comment: @NikVladi by the thread doing the `Dispose()`? they are indeed sequential; the GC, however, has a separate thread and can do *what it wants*. But: if you aren't dealing with unmanaged data (typically pointers): **none of this applies**, and you're likely to be over-complicating things. Heck, you shouldn't even *have* a finalizer if you don't have unmanaged data

Comment: @MarcGravell I correctly understood that the operation `GC.SuppressFinalize (this)` is performed by a separate thread within the framework of the GC and can be performed in parallel with the long execution of `this.Dispose (true)`?

Comment: Just to be explicit: `lock` is not a good idea here. Fortunately, the implied `Monitor.Exit` will function the same as `GC.KeepAlive` and will prevent it being collected, because if you ever *did* manage to hit a `lock` (`Monitor.[Try]Enter`) in the GC thread, you've completely killed your app (it can never become unlocked). So it would work, but for all the wrong reasons!

Comment: I need to emphasize something else important too: "I am new to programming" - you are probably worrying *way, way too much about this*: this is an extremely niche edge case that applies in a tiny majority of *some of the absolutely most complex code imagineable*. Most .NET developers will never have need to directly touch finalizers or unmanged data. I've been working full time with .NET for ... 15+ years? And these issues have applied *once maybe twice* (and I routinely deal with the "scary end" of .NET scenarios)

Comment: @MarcGravell The book says this and there are not many examples, I thought it was important and I needed to figure it out.

Comment: @nikvladi no, the `GC.SuppressFinalize(this)` doesn't get run on a separate thread; that just happens on the same thread that is calling `Dispose()`, which calls `Dispose(true)`. The **garbage collector** (GC) has a separate thread, which could hypothetically enter via `~Example()`, calling `Dispose(false)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1) Here I have a first question, how is this possible? After all, GC CLR destroys the object as correctly noticed when there are no more links to it. But if there are no references, how then can simultaneously still work the method of an object (Dispose()) to which nothing else refers? Yes, there are no links, but the method is not completed and GC CLR will try to delete the method object that still works?

Imagine that you have a method like:

```cs
void SomeMethod()
{
    var unmanagedPtr = this.MyPointer;
    while (/* some long loop */)
    {
        // lots of code that *just* uses unmanagedPtr
    }
}
```

Now; `this` here is `arg0`, so *does exist* in the stack, but the `GC` is allowed to look at when locals are *read*, and `arg0` is not read past the first few instructions; so from the perspective of `GC`, it can ignore `arg0` if the thread is in the `while` loop. Now; imagine that *somehow* the reference to this object *only* exists in `arg0` - perhaps because it was only ever transient on the stack, i.e.

```cs
new MyType(...).SomeMethod();
```

*At this point*, yes, the object can be collected even though a method is executing on it. In most scenarios, we would never notice any side effect from this, but: finalizers and unmanaged data is a bit of a special case, beause if your *finalizer* invalidates the `unmanagedPtr` that the `while` loop is depending on: bad things.

The *most appropriate fix here*, is probably to just add `GC.KeepAlive(this)` to the end of `SomeMethod`. Importantly, note that `GC.KeepAlive` **does literally nothing** - it is an opaque, no-op, non-inlineable method, *nothing else*. All we're actually doing by adding `GC.KeepAlive(this)` is adding a read against `arg0`, which means that the GC needs to *look* at `arg0`, so it notices that the object is still reachable, and doesn't get collected.

> 2) Which in the proposed last solution will not allow GC CLR to call the this.Dispose(false) method in its thread in parallel through the destructor in the same way as before while this.Dispose(true) will still be executed previously launched explicitly?

For us to be able to call `Dispose()`, we clearly have a reference, so that's good. So we know it was reachable at least until `Dispose`, and we're only talking about `Dispose(true)` competing with `Dispose(false)`. In this scenario, the `GC.SuppressFinalize(this)` serves two purposes:

- the mere existence of `GC.SuppressFinalize(this)` acts the same as `GC.KeepAlive` and marks the object as reachable; it can't possibly be collected until that point is reached
- and once it has been reached, it won't get finalized *at all*

Answer (score 1):

---

> it is possible that the finalizer might actually be invoked by the garbage collector on its own thread while the Dispose method is being run
>
> (...)
>
> how is this possible?

A local variable that references an object, which will no longer be used in the method, does not prevent garbage collection.

Please refer to [When does an object become available for garbage collection?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100810-00/?p=13193).

In the article, Raymond shows that an object can become elegible for garbage collection during the execution of one of its methods.

The following code was completed starting fromthe the snippets of the article:

```
class Color
{
    // ...
}

class SomeClass
{
    string SomeMethod(string s, bool reformulate)
    {
        OtherClass o = new OtherClass(s);
        string result = Frob(o);
        // o is elegible for garbage collection here
        if (reformulate)
        {
            Reformulate();
        }
        return result;
    }

    string Frob(OtherClass o)
    {
        string result = FrobColor(o.GetEffectiveColor());
        // o is elegible for garbage collection here
        return result;
    }

    string FrobColor(Color color)
    {
        return color.ToString();
    }

    void Reformulate()
    {
        // ...
    }
}

class OtherClass
{
    public OtherClass(string s)
    {
        _ = s;
    }

    OtherClass Parent {get; set;}

    Color Color {get; set;}

    public Color GetEffectiveColor()
    {
        Color color = this.Color;
        for (OtherClass o = this.Parent; o != null; o = o.Parent)
        {
            // this is elegible for garbage collection here
            color = BlendColors(color, o.Color);
        }
        return color;
    }

    static Color BlendColors(Color left, Color right)
    {
        _ = right;
        return left;
    }
}
```

Please note that the garbage collector does scan the stack for references. Thus, for this to work, inlining is required.

It is also worth noting that `this` is not a root for the garbage collector, nor the finalizer thread.

*And that is without talking about `WeakReference`*

---

The situation where the finalizer and the dispose methods to be running at the same time is very unlikely.

However, you need to decide if your type is meant to be thread safe. If that is the case, you should worry about two consumer threads calling dispose.

And this pattern is not thread safe:

```
if (!this.disposed)
{
    // ...
    this.disposed = true;
}
```

I would suggest to update and check a `disposed` field with an interlocked operation:

```
if (Interlocked.Exchange(_disposed, 1) == 0)
{
    // ...
}
```

However, dealing with managed resources should just call `Dispose` and set to null. You can do that like this:

```
Interlocked.Exchange(ref _managedResource, null)?.Dispose();
```

---

> (...) I have problems with mentioning exactly the parallel execution of this.Dispose(true) and this.Dispose(false)

If the finalizer always calls `Dispose(false)`, while `Dispose` calls `Dispose(true)`. You know that the code under the conditional `disposing == true` will only run from `Dispose`. And thus, it will not be running in parallel from the finalizer.

In addition to that, the execution of `GC.SuppressFinalize(this)` prevents finalization. Since there is a reference to `this`, the object is not eligible before the call to `SuppressFinalize` and, the call prevents the finalization completely.

---

I will remind you that the order of finalization is not deterministic. During the execution of the finalizer, the reference type fields of the object being finalized could have been finalized already. There are no guarantees about there order. Because of that, you should not be acceding them from the finalizer.

In fact, I would like to encourage to do not have objects that deal with both managed and unmanaged resources at the same time. By virtue of single responsibility principle, wrap any unmanaged resources in managed ones (you deal with them by calling some external API). 
And then classes that need them only have to deal with managed resources (and dealing with them is just calling `Dispose)`.

Furthermore, if you do not have unmanaged resources, avoid the finalizer.